# How can we reset Liferay Audience Targeting Score

Tags: java, plugins, liferay-7, target-audience

I am using Liferay DXP EE SP6 Tomcat bundle with Audience Targeting EE plugin.

I have been able to deploy, setup and configure Audience Targeting. I created user segments and a campaign after watching the demo below:

https://web.liferay.com/web/fady.hakim/blog/-/blogs/liferay-dxp-demo-videos

It works well out of the box. I used the Score = 2 to define the user segment.

Does anyone know how the score can be reset/cleared? Is this available out of the box or does it need customization?

Clearing my Chrome cache repeatedly did not reset the score for an anonymous user once the campaign content shows for a user after 2 clicks to a target page. The score does get reset somehow by itself after a few days.

Thanks a lot for the insight!

Comment: You're using DXP, which means that you can easily file a support ticket. Alternatively please try the Liferay forums. This question is not programming related, thus not a good fit for stackoverflow - I'm voting to close for this reasons.

Comment: Thanks Olaf for the feedback. I am not sure that the reset/clear score analytics features exists in Audience targeting.  If so, I wanted to find out if this was an enhancement/customization that needed to be made. In this case, it is a programing question. I would like to know if someone has done this before. Please let me know if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a reply from Eduardo on this.

https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/99604379

Excerpt:
If you're talking about the Score Points rule, then the scores assigned to a user for a user segment are stored in their own service (ScorePointService) table. Out-of-the-box, you cannot reset this information manually. You would have to remove the information from the table in the DB and clean the Liferay DB cache. However, you could easily create an extension for AT that - for instance - allows removing all the assigned scores for a given user, for a given user segment or for both.